# how to import project from github?

Tags: eclipse, github

According to the github link below i should have to generate eclipse metadata. (i'm currently using eclipse) but i dont know what does this mean and how to do it. it just says ./gradlew eclipse and i dont know how can i import it . can anyone please share step by step on detail how to generate it (what button should i click in eclipse or what software should i run ) ?

here is the link :
https://github.com/joshlong/spring-integration-mqtt

Comment: File -> New -> Project from version control

Comment: @AndreyIlyunin maybe you should post that as an answer

Comment: @jhamon, okay..

Comment: Download the project from github and import to the eclipse or get the clone of the github project and using Egit plugin to import the project to the eclipse.

Comment: It does say how to create eclipse metadata as well as how to import in the document itself. To generate Eclipse metadata (.classpath and .project files), do the following: `./gradlew eclipse` Once complete, you may then import the projects into Eclipse as usual: `File -> Import -> Existing projects into workspace`

Comment: @ManojPrabhakarM i already tried to import it but it just cant. it says no projects are found to import

Comment: @user20 Then, you go for Egit plugin [link](http://www.eclipse.org/egit/download/). Then restart the eclipse. You have option for import project from git.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First check in Window> show view > search Git > if you see git option there you process to step 3. Else step 1.

```
Steps :
1 : Go to Help > Market Place > Search git and install Git (version control plugin)
2 : After install restart the eclipse (will be asked automatically to reflect changes)
3 : Go to File > Import > Git > Project from git > Enter your git repo path and and you are there
Then select projects and boom it's in your eclipse workspace
```

Answer (score -1):

File -> New -> Project from version control